# Ubuntu Server Hacked -- What I can do to figure out how and to prevent it?

Tags: ubuntu, security

My server is hacked. It happens every day. I restart it and it works for a while before it goes down again. I am wondering if anyone in the community has had a similar issue and how did they resolve it?

There are a few things from what I can see. First, there are users added to the database. Second, it happens daily around 6:40 AM. Third, the CPU load goes to 100% while there are almost no processes running.

It is a [Linode](https://www.linode.com) server with Ubuntu, running Apache, MySQL and PHP 7.1. There is a Laravel web application as the main application, along with WordPress and some other software.

`htop` shows this:

[image: htop screenshot]

`top`, `ps aux`, etc. have similar output. CPU load is 100%, while all processes add up to 5 - 6%.

The Apache and all the other logs are showing some activity. I can see a link to some porn site here:

[image: link to porn screenshot]

The MySQL log shows that it has shut down:

[MySQL log screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wEWVI.png)

And these are the graphs:

[image: graphs screenshot]

Another weird thing in the Apache `access` log is this entry:

[image: Apache access log screenshot]

Here are the two entries in text format:

```
103.23.35.167 - - [31/Jan/2019:06:28:01 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 302 1309 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) Apple WebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/52.0.2743.116 Safari/537.36"
109.252.14.217 - - [31/Jan/2019:06:37:24 +0000] "\xc1\r\x07\x10;\xb51Y\xe0\xf0\x16+\xe0\x13I\x1a\xe1\xffc\x9c3M\xae\x19^\xe9\x9e\x16\x1d\x8d\x19\x9b\xab\x98\xa8?\xf8\xc19N[,\xb8\xb2\x95-\x15\x1f\x8f\x86\xfa\xf7\xdeP\xb8\xbf\x88Yq\x92lC\xb5\x8b$p\x03\xa0\xb7\xe0\x9em\x10\xc1\x07\x91rx\x98\xd3C$@\xb4\xea\xff\xbb\x89\xd8l8I\x0el\xd8\x94\xa5\xa3yGJc\xab\x1e\xcb\xe0#\xdfN\x01 \x120\x1e3\v\x97[\xbd.\xb0\xf3Qz-\x81_\xee\x1bpn\xe3y\xa6\x7f\xac\xd7TH\xb4\xb5.W\x82a\xa3\x97I\xb01\xba\x0e\xe1\xdc\xf6\x17#\x05\x91\xfcZ\xa4\xe9\x18t`\xd6\xa1\x18\xb0\xbd'\x02\xb7=\x98\xee;\x1f{\xd3\xc1\xef\xbb\xf1\x96=\x85\xce\xfe\x12w\xffb\xdc\xb8\x05\xeb3~\xeeE\x18Cf\x8dF\xf2Lm;\x86\r\x1a7\xfc~\xfb\xce\x99\xc2\xff\xf9\x94\xe6\x9b\xb6x/1v\x85\x88\x8b\xd1\xc7~)K\r0\x04\x99}\xaf\x17\x7fp2\x80<\x8bb9TO2\xf7\x9d/\xaa\xe9\x88\xec\xb4\x14F\x1d\xc5H\x18q\xba\xa3Wg/\x9e\n" 400 0 "-" "-"
31.24.207.139 - - [31/Jan/2019:06:46:12 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 15532 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_6) AppleWebKit/601.7.7 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/9.1.2 Safari/601.7.7"
```

and

```
51.75.66.250 - - [02/Feb/2019:08:55:36 +0000] "GET /mysite/ HTTP/1.0" 301 545 "http://porn.auntie.hotblognetwork.com" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/67.0.3396.87 Safari/537.36"
51.75.66.250 - - [02/Feb/2019:08:55:39 +0000] "GET /mysite/ HTTP/1.0" 500 3828 "https://appsforce.org/mysite/" "Mozilla/
```

Any ideas or suggestions are welcome.

Comment: The only thing you can do is basically clean up your code and possible nuke the server and redeploy the code on the new server.  I would recommend installing Sucuri Security plug-in and then reviewing the tips on [this Sucuri site page](https://sucuri.net/guides/how-to-clean-hacked-wordpress-a?utm_expid=.bDk7l0PdRtyZciZWQTXqRg.1&utm_referrer=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2F).

Comment: Actually, looking at this, you are right - Those python scripts are running as root.  Its game over for that VM.

Comment: _Apps Force_, it is a heck of a lot easier to read text than to read a screen shot. For future use, the screenshot 1, 2, and 4 could be replaced with text; can't do anything about #3 since it is a graph.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing I notice is that one of those requests seems to be shellcode from 109.252.14.217. That IP doesn't show up on any proxy/VPN lists, but it also doesn't mean that its your "cracker's" real IP. Above someone said that your server is done for because of that python script running as root. Which is not necessarily true. It is very bad, but not a death sentence. The first thing I would do (if you can) is reboot. If the attacker hasn't gotten persistence yet then that could kill his shell if he has one. Check your bash history file for any suspicious looking commands that you haven't entered, recent modification, or lack of anything in it. If the cracker is clumsy he'll leave traces there. Run "netstat -np" to see if there are any suspicious connections. If there is a reverse TCP or HTTP connection and it's tied to the PID of that running python program then either block it with your firewall or kill the process. These are some of the first things I would do. But I'm no hacker so...